# Nested Default Maps in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, default

I'm trying to construct nested maps in Scala, where both the outer and inner map use the "withDefaultValue" method.  For example, the following :

```
val m = HashMap.empty[Int, collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int]].withDefaultValue( HashMap.empty[Int,Int].withDefaultValue(3))
m(1)(2)
res: Int = 3
m(1)(2) = 5
m(1)(2) 
res: Int = 5
m(2)(3) = 6
m
res : scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int]] = Map()
```

So the map, when addressed by the appropriate keys, gives me back what I put in.  However, the map itself appears empty!  Even m.size returns 0 in this example.  Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Short answer

It's definitely not a bug.

### Long answer

The behavior of `withDefaultValue` is to store a default value (in your case, a mutable map) inside the Map to be returned in the case that they key does not exist.  This is not the same as a value that is *inserted* into the Map when they key is not found.

Let's look closely at what's happening.  It will be easier to understand if we pull the default map out as a separate variable so we can inspect is at will; let's call it `default`

```
import collection.mutable.HashMap
val default = HashMap.empty[Int,Int].withDefaultValue(3)
```

So `default` is a mutable map (that has its own default value).  Now we can create `m` and give `default` as the default value.

```
import collection.mutable.{Map => MMap}
val m = HashMap.empty[Int, MMap[Int,Int]].withDefaultValue(default)
```

Now whenever `m` is accessed with a missing key, it will return `default`.  Notice that this is the exact same behavior as you have because `withDefaultValue` is defined as:

```
def withDefaultValue (d: B): Map[A, B]
```

Notice that it's `d: B` and not `d: => B`, so it will not create a new map each time the default is accessed; it will return the same exact object, what we've called `default`.

So let's see what happens:

```
m(1) // Map()
```

Since key 1 is not in `m`, the default, `default` is returned.  `default` at this time is an empty Map.

```
m(1)(2) = 5
```

Since `m(1)` returns `default`, this operation stores 5 as the value for key 2 in `default`.  Nothing is written to the Map `m` because `m(1)` resolves to `default` which is a separate Map entirely.  We can check this by viewing `default`:

```
default // Map(2 -> 5)
```

But as we said, `m` is left unchanged

```
m // Map()
```

---

Now, how to achieve what you really wanted?  Instead of using `withDefaultValue`, you want to make use of `getOrElseUpdate`:

```
def getOrElseUpdate (key: A, op: ⇒ B): B
```

Notice how we see `op: => B`?  This means that the argument `op` will be re-evaluated each time it is needed.  This allows us to put a new Map in there and have it be a separate new Map for each invalid key.  Let's take a look:

```
val m2 = HashMap.empty[Int, MMap[Int,Int]]
```

No default values needed here.

```
m2.getOrElseUpdate(1, HashMap.empty[Int,Int].withDefaultValue(3)) // Map()
```

Key 1 doesn't exist, so we insert a new HashMap, and return that new value.  We can check that it was inserted as we expected.  Notice that 1 maps to the newly added empty map and that they 3 was not added anywhere because of the behavior explained above.

```
m2 // Map(1 -> Map())
```

Likewise, we can update the Map as expected:

```
m2.getOrElseUpdate(1, HashMap.empty[Int,Int].withDefaultValue(1))(2) = 6
```

and check that it was added:

```
m2 // Map(1 -> Map(2 -> 6))
```

Comment: I get it now; the breakdown helped a lot.  It's interesting how strongly my initial bias about how I thought the function _should_ work prevented me from seeing what was actually going on.

Answer (score 2):

`withDefaultValue` is used to return a value when the key was not found. It does not populate the map. So you map stays empty. Somewhat like using `getOrElse(a, b)` where `b` is provided by `withDefaultValue`.

Comment: Sure, but when I call m(1)(2) = 5, that should place the value 5 in the map.  Why, then, does the map appear empty after performing this "update()"?

Comment: @nomad I'm quite intrigued by the interesting behavior here, but it all actually makes a lot of sense.  m **is** still empty after that update, because what you updated was **not** m; you updated one of m's default values.  That is, you updated the map that is referenced by m(1) until m(1) gets an actual value.  Since you changed the size of **that** map, and since you've never updated any of **m's** key-value pairs, m is still empty, as far as it's concerned.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the exact same problem, and was happy to find dhg's answer. Since typing getOrElseUpdate all the time is not very concise, I came up with this little extension of the idea that I want to share:
You can declare a class that uses getOrElseUpdate as default behavior for the () operator:

```
class DefaultDict[K, V](defaultFunction: (K) => V) extends HashMap[K, V] {
  override def default(key: K): V = return defaultFunction(key)
  override def apply(key: K): V = 
    getOrElseUpdate(key, default(key))
}
```

Now you can do what you want to do like this:

```
var map = new DefaultDict[Int, DefaultDict[Int, Int]](
  key => new DefaultDict(key => 3))
map(1)(2) = 5
```

Which does now result in `map` containing 5 (or rather: containing a DefaultDict containing the value 5 for the key 2).

Comment: Please don't. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the effect that you've created a single `Map[Int, Int]` this is the default value whenever the key isn't in the outer map.

```
scala> val m = HashMap.empty[Int, collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int]].withDefaultValue( HashMap.empty[Int,Int].withDefaultValue(3))
m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int]] = Map()

scala> m(2)(2)
res1: Int = 3

scala> m(1)(2) = 5

scala> m(2)(2)
res2: Int = 5
```

To get the effect that you're looking for, you'll have to wrap the `Map` with an implementation that actually inserts the default value when a key isn't found in the `Map`.

***Edit:***

I'm not sure what your actual use case is, but you may have an easier time using a pair for the key to a single `Map`.

```
scala> val m = HashMap.empty[(Int, Int), Int].withDefaultValue(3)
m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[(Int, Int),Int] = Map()

scala> m((1, 2))
res0: Int = 3

scala> m((1, 2)) = 5

scala> m((1, 2))
res3: Int = 5

scala> m
res4: scala.collection.mutable.Map[(Int, Int),Int] = Map((1,2) -> 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but I've just seen the post while I was trying to solve the same problem.
Probably the API are different from the 2012 version but you may want to use `withDefault`instead that `withDefaultValue`.
The difference is that `withDefault` takes a function as parameter, that is executed every time a missed key is requested ;)